# Shows error when I use an if statment to check leaderstats?

Tags: lua, roblox

Basically what i want happening is that this code will give me a tool depending on their leaderstats value, the problem is that it will not give me the tool. Heres the code

Server script

```
-- Server script
game.ReplicatedStorage.Events.Cyborg.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
    
    local leaderstats = player.leaderstats
    local Milk = leaderstats.Points
    
    if player.leaderstats.Points.Value >= 700 then
        player.leaderstats.Points.Value = player.leaderstats.Points.Value - 700
        
        game.ServerStorage.Cyborg:Clone().Parent = player.Backpack
    end
end)
```

And the client script

```
-- Client script aka Button dectector
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    game.ReplicatedStorage.Events.Cyborg:FireServer()
end)
```

It will not give me my gear in serverstorage. Can someone help me and **provide the correct code**?

Comment: and what error would that be? please provide more information

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can't clone stuff from the ServerStorage directly to the LocalPlayer. You would need to parent it to the ReplicatedStorage, then parent it to the LocalPlayer. Again, I'm no expert at this, but that's what I can make out.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot clone objects from the server storage in Roblox as it is exclusively used to store stuff while you are on Roblox Studio. In order to make this work you simply have to change the item location into something else (recommended: replicatedStorage). I would also recommend using as little variables as possible in order to waste less memory. Instead of having a variable for leaderstats and one for points just make a single one that gets the points.